# Symfony2 embedded form - get entity field

Tags: php, symfony, twig, entity-relationship

I have an entity with a many-to-many association.
What I'm trying to do is:

- create the form for the main entity
- embed the associated entities

I have been able to do both the points above, but now I cannot figure out how to retrieve an  associated entity field.

My classes are **Gallery** and **Immagine**. **Immagine** has 3 properties, **image**, **imageName** and **file**.

Inside my GalleryType buildForm function I do this:

```
->add('immagini', 'entity', array(
  'class' => 'MySiteBundle:Immagine',
  'property' => 'image',
  'multiple' => true,
  'expanded' => true
))
```

Now, in my edit.html.twig template, if I write this

```
{% for img in edit_form.immagini %}
  <li>
    {{ form_widget(img, {'attr': {'style': 'vertical-align: top'}} ) }}
    {{ form_label(img, null,  { 'label_attr': {'style': 'display: inline'}} ) }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

...and the result of embedded images inside a gallery edit page, is correct and works great.
[image]

Now, what I want to do is to display in the same li tag, another **Immagine** field, let's say **imageName**.
I've tryed so many ways, but I'm not able to do it...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should embed your associated entity by using collection type, not entity type like you did.

```
->add('immagini','collection',array('type'=>new ImageType(),'multiple'=>...,))
```

So, you need to implement a new form class, call it what you like eg. ImageType(). In that class type add whatever form types(properties) you would need to display, eg.

```
->add('imageName','text')
->add(...
```

Than you would be able to iterate and display it from twig code.

Take a look at basic form embedding docs:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html

Comment: ...no, it doesn't work. Without the multiple option in the formBuilder it shows the form of a single Immagine, and the multiple option it says me that does not exist. Can't I call the entity method to retrieve an attribute?